# Not allowing to use Constant defined in Objective C header file in swift class. Undefined symbols for architecture armv7

Tags: objective-c, swift, arm7

I created **Objective C Header file**. and added some properties in it.
i declared
 `static NSString* const kColor005C98 = @"005C98";` in `Constants.h` file

I defined this file in **Bridging-Header** file as `#import "Constants.h"`
Now when i want to use this property `kColor005C98` in some **swift** file it failed the build and i am getting

> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7: "_kColor005C98", referenced from:

i don't know what else i need to do so i don't get this error? (i have used this property in other **objective C** file successfully and no issue in that case)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Update:**

As of Swift 2/Xcode 7 and later, a static constant definition like

```
static NSString* const kColor005C98 = @"005C98"; // in Constants.h file
```

is imported to Swift and can be used without problems.

---

*(Old answer for Swift 1.x)* When the code

```
static NSString* const kColor005C98 = @"005C98"; // in Constants.h file
```

is processed by an *Objective-C* compiler, it is treated as two things
combined into one statement:

- A variable *declaration* which introduces an identifier and describes its type, and
- a variable *definition* which actually instantiates/implements this identifier.

See for example
[What is the difference between a definition and a declaration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration)
for a good explanation of the difference between declaration and
definition.

The Swift compiler treats the statement only as a declaration.
Therefore the variable is not defined anywhere, causing the linker error.

To solve the problem, you have to move the *definition* to an Objective-C
file:

```
// Constants.m:
#import "Constants.h"
NSString * const kColor005C98  = @"005C98";
```

and change the *declaration* to an `extern` declaration:

```
// Constants.h:
extern NSString * const kColor005C98;
```

*Alternatively,* you can just remove the `static` modifier:

```
 NSString * const kColor005C98 = @"005C98";
```

to make it work with Swift. The disadvantage is that when 
this line is included by multiple Objective-C files, all of them
will define a globally visible symbol `kColor005C98`, causing
"duplicate symbol" linker errors.

*Another alternative* is to use a macro definition instead:

```
#define kColor005C98 @"005C98"
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. I tried this but now i am getting "Expression is not an integer constant expression in iOS" error in Switch statement if i use NSInteger constant.

Comment: @WaseemKhan: I am sure that this works with integer constants as well, and it is difficult to help without seeing the actual code.

Comment: i declared like this `extern NSInteger const someIntegerConstant;` in `Constants.h` file and defined as 
`NSInteger const someIntegerConstant = 1;` in 'Constants.m' file
Now i am using it in switch statement like this 

`switch (someConditiom){
case someIntegerConstant:
// some code here
}`

 and getting "Expression is not an integer constant expression" Error

Comment: @WaseemKhan: Strange. That exact code compiles without problems in my test app.

Comment: @WaseemKhan: Do you get the error message in an *Objective-C* file? In (Objective-C), the switch cases cannot be used with variables.

Comment: Yep. getting that msg in Objective C.

Comment: but i was using the same in objective C when i declared it like `static NSInteger const someIntegerConstant = 1;` now with ur solution i removed the `static` keyword and changed to `extern` and provided declaration and implementation seperately. then i started getting above `Expression is not an integer constant expression` problem

Comment: @WaseemKhan: I see. What you can do is: Declare two variables `static NSInteger const someIntegerConstant = 1;` and `extern NSInteger const swiftIntegerConstant;` in Constants.h, and define `NSInteger const swiftIntegerConstant = someIntegerConstant;` in Constants.m. Then you can use `someIntegerConstant` as a real constant in Objective-C files, and you can use `someIntegerConstant` in Swift files. – Sorry, I could not find a nicer solution.

Comment: i will have to find some other nice solution because i have too many such variables in my `constants.h` file. i can't duplicate them all :(

Comment: This really helped me out after a long, long search on a partially related problem. The C library I was trying to bridge had a bunch of static declarations. Tried to figure out how to bridge them, ultimately just removed the statics based on this post. Thanks!

Comment: @WaseemKhan: Things have simplified with newer Swift/Xcode versions ...