# Use C static char arrays in Swift via bridge header

Tags: c, swift, linker

I would like to use some static char arrays in Swift using the bridge header functionality. In my bridge header I've declared this variable:

```
static char test[] = {
    0x74, 0x65, 0x73, 0x74
};
```

and I'm using it in my app delegate (just testing right now) like this:

```
let string = withUnsafePointer(&test) {
    String.fromCString(UnsafePointer($0))!
}
```

But I'm getting a linker error because apparently the symbol _test is not defined.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28577147/not-allowing-to-use-constant-defined-in-objective-c-header-file-in-swift-class.

Comment: Note also that `String.fromCString()` expects a NUL-terminated C string.